# Error in mysqli after pagination

Tags: php, pagination

It's me again, sorry...
I've been looking for the answer right in this forums, but there are no posts has been solved. I don't know if the questioner has been resolved the problems and not given a solved comment or something like that. All the comments/replies from the questioner is 'not work' or 'get some new errors' ect.

Now my scripts has worked before I put pagination scripts on them, but again errors in 'mysqli'. The errors are:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\paging\index.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\paging\index.php on line 9
```

My scripts contained two files:

**index.php:**

```
 <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_book") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $per_page = 3; 

    //getting number of rows and calculating no of pages

    $sql    = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flipbook";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    $count  = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $pages  = ceil($count[0]/$per_page);

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>DIGITAL LIBRARY</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
    libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="pagination.js"></script>    
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family:Verdana; font-size:15px }
    a
    {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#B2b2b2;

    }

    a:hover
    {

    color:#DF3D82;
    text-decoration:underline;

    }
    #loading { 
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    }

    #pagination
    {
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:120px;

    }
    li{ 
    list-style: none; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 16px; 
    padding:5px; 
    border:solid 1px #dddddd;
    color:#0063DC; 
    }
    li:hover
    { 
    color:#FF0084; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
       <div style="margin-top:50px;"></div>
     <div id="content" ></div>
        <table width="800px">
        <tr><Td>
                <ul id="pagination">
                    <?php
                    //Show page links
                    for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
                    {
                        echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
                    }
                    ?>
               </ul>    
            </Td>
        </tr></table>
    <div id="loading" ></div>
        </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

**and data.php:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_book");

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT b.*, title, author_name, url_flipbook, p.publisher_name, ct.cat_name FROM biblioflip AS b
                       LEFT JOIN mst_publisherflip AS p ON b.publisher_id=p.publisher_id
                       LEFT JOIN mst_catflip AS ct ON b.cat_id=ct.cat_id
                       ORDER BY flip_id limit $start,$per_page") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$per_page = 3; 
if($_GET)
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}

//getting table contents
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
?>


<table id="tbl">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Publisher</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Link</th>
        <?php
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {     
            $title      = $row['title'];
            $author     = $row['author_name'];
            $publisher  = $row['publisher_name'];
            $category   = $row['cat_name'];
            $link       = '<a href="' . $row['url_flipbook'] . '">FLIPBOOK</a></td>';
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $author; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $publisher; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $link; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        } //End while
    mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
</table>

<style>
#tbl
{
width:800px;
border:1px solid #98bf21;
margin-top:50px;
}

#tbl tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EAF2D3
}

#tbl td{
border:1px solid #98bf21
}

#tbl th
{
  background: #A7C942;
border:1px solid #98bf21
}
</style>
```

Thanks again...thank you...

best regards,

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite descriptive and clear: The first parameter to `mysqli_query` should be the connection handle.

Instead of `$result = mysqli_query($sql);`, use `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);`

Comment: yes it works, but the index pages only displayed number '1'. Only the number showed up. But not the data. Do I have to open asking post again?

Comment: In data.php, you're using `$start` and `$per_page` in the query before actually defining them, which happens on the next lines. You should fix that first.